# E-commerce website requires SSL?

Tags: php, web-services, e-commerce

I am developing an ecommerce website for a gift store, where the physical products will be sold and shipped to the customer.

We are planning to integrate with payment gateway for payment processing.

My question here is, as the payment processing is being handled by an external party, do i still need to have SSL Certificate for my domain.

Please advise and thanks in advance for your time and expertise.

Comment: No you don't.  If you handle any customer information I think you should though.

Comment: Thanks @shapeshifter.  I am not handling any customer information in my website.

Comment: If its an option it is more professional to have a valid SSL certificate.

Comment: If its an e-commerce website you should have SSL on every page. Its inexpensive and provides many benefits including more sales because customers will have more trust.